# running tomcat, what are my options?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

If I am running the tomcat java container on a server, does it require me to use apache?

What options do I have?

If I need apache, what book would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use apache..  You could allow access directly to Tomcat, but beware, the HTTP Auth support is pretty appalling if you don't have a server as proxy for Tomcat.

You could use a number of other servers, for example nginx can act as a proxy server for Tomcat.

You don't need to buy any books, you can do pretty well with the available documentation for both Apache Server, and Tomcat.

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxJavaServers (I've not tried this)

[This is a pretty damn good book on Tomcat..](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101066)

Comment: it seems nginx is the choice for webservers, would you suggest I look into nginx over apache?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Tomcat can run stand alone.  However, it's not very efficient at serving static HTML.

If your site has a mix of static and dynamic content then you should consider running Apache (on port 80) and use the [connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi) to integrate tomcat.  This also gives you much more fine grained access controls that come with Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using **varnish** in front of tomcat instead of Apache, because Apache's tomcat connector is quite *b0rken*.

Varnish is a very efficient reverse proxy and cache and speeds up delivery of tomcat's HTML output. Without the hassle of tomcat connector.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is not required; you may use another Web server or none at all, depending on what your Java application is doing.  See [Tomcat connector documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors)